# What is the difference between net/rpc .Call vs .Go?

Tags: go, rpc

I’m just getting started with Golang and the net/rpc package. I’m trying to understand when you might use the asynchronous client.Go() call over the client.Call() method most examples online use. Would calling client.Call asynchronously via something like

```
go client.Call(...)
```

essentially be the same as using the client.Go call? I’ve seen this example online too (for example when calling multiple simultaneous RPCs).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [documented](https://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/#Client.Go):

> Go invokes the function asynchronously. It returns the Call structure representing the invocation. The done channel will signal when the call is complete by returning the same Call object. If done is nil, Go will allocate a new channel. If non-nil, done must be buffered or Go will deliberately crash.

What this means is that it issues the command, *but does not wait for it to finish*.

By [contrast](https://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/#Client.Call):

> Call invokes the named function, waits for it to complete, and returns its error status.

Neither method executes in a goroutine directly*--this is left as an exercise for the caller (so an argument might be made that `Go` is a misnomer).

If you look at the [source to `Call`](https://golang.org/src/net/rpc/client.go?s=9009:9100#L311), perhaps it is more clear:

```
func (client *Client) Call(serviceMethod string, args interface{}, reply 
interface{}) error {
    call := <-client.Go(serviceMethod, args, reply, make(chan *Call, 1)).Done
    return call.Error
}
```

So in actuality, `Call` is a wrapper around `Go`, which waits for the operation to complete, whereas `Go` is the underlying function, which leaves waiting up to the caller.

*Clearly, in the background, a goroutine is involved somewhere, since this is a non-blocking operation.